# Como excluir um registro de uma tabela na view sem deletar do banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema a nível de didático e na minha view eu tenho uma tabela que exibe os dados de um funcionário cadastrado pelo usuário. 
Na view tem os botões editar e deletar, só que o deletar está apagando também os
o registro no banco de dados. Para manter a integridade dos dados eu preciso apagar somente o funcionário na view para o usuário e manter o registro salvo no banco.

Alguém pode me ajudar em como eu posso fazer isso?

Estou usando o Laravel 5.6 / PHP 7.2.3 / MySQL

Comment: Uma dica, crie um campo, exp: `hidden` como boolean, ai se quiser excluir da view é so setar como true, e listar na sua view mais ou menos assim: `$books->isHidden(false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Laravel tem uma *feature* chamada [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting) (exclusão lógica) que permite que se exclua um registro logicamente sem apagá-lo do banco de dados.

Para o Laravel reconhecer um registro como excluído é necessário que:

- a tabela contenha o campo `deleted_at` (do tipo `TIMESTAMP`);
- o Model use a *trait* `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`
- se adicione na propriedade `$dates` do Model o valor `'deleted_at'`

Dessa maneira os registros que tiverem o campo `'deleted_at' IS NOT NULL`. Serão considerados registros excluídos e não serão inclusos nos resultados do Eloquent.

Caso seja necessário mostrar todos os registros, incluindo os "excluídos", pode-se usar o seguinte método:

```php
<?php

// Todos Models
App\Model::withTrashed()->all();

// Apenas excluídos
App\Model::onlyTrashed()->all();
```

Veja os [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting) para mais informações.

---

**Exemplo de classe**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Exemplo extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

**Exemplo de migration**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateExemploTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exemplo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary('id');
            // ...
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Fernando, muito obrigado mesmo. No caso eu iria colocar o atributo deleted_at como boolen correto?

Comment: Na verdade é um `TIMESTAMP` onde o Laravel testa se for `NULL` é porque não foi excluído, e se não for `NULL` o campo tem a data da exclusão.
Se tu olhar o [código do migrations](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ad52d1cc1fd314b4f617a5941bbb543f9f05e2e7/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L988) tu vai ver que quando se chama `$table->softDeletes()` o schema builder cria um `TIMESTAMP` mesmo.

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez, conseguir entender e irei aplicar aqui. Abraço.